# Lipics has no chapter numbers

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I'm trying to modify the [lipicsmaster](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/styles/lipics/lipics-editors.tgz) document class in order to make the chapter number available: as you could see in `lipics-sample-frontmatter.tex`, the **Preface** chapter has no number. How could I redefine the class in order to update `\thechapter` counter and put such number inside the box defined in the following part of code?

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent\z@ \raggedright
   \hangindent12\p@ \advance\hangindent1em
   \textcolor[rgb]{0.99,0.78,0.07}{\rule{12\p@}{12\p@}}\quad
   \LARGE\sffamily\bfseries\mathversion{bold}#1\par}%
  \vskip2\baselineskip}
```

I've noticed that the sections within different chapter have the same chapter number, that is zero. In case that this thing is possible, could I even define a `\chapter*` command that does not display the chapter number as the default lipicsmaster behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{0.99,0.78,0.07}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent\z@ \raggedright
   \hangindent12\p@ \advance\hangindent1em
   \refstepcounter{chapter}%
   %\textcolor[rgb]{0.99,0.78,0.07}{\rule{12\p@}{12\p@}}\quad
   \colorbox{myyellow}{\resizebox{12\p@}{12\p@}{\textcolor{black}{\sffamily\thechapter}}}\quad%
   \LARGE\sffamily\bfseries\mathversion{bold}#1\par}%
  \vskip2\baselineskip}
\makeatother
```

[image]

You may wish to add a specification to marginally change the display of a `\chapter*` to match the above redefinition associated with `\chapter`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent\z@ \raggedright
   \hangindent12\p@ \advance\hangindent1em
   %\textcolor[rgb]{0.99,0.78,0.07}{\rule{12\p@}{12\p@}}\quad
   \colorbox{myyellow}{\resizebox{12\p@}{12\p@}{\phantom{\sffamily\thechapter}}}\quad%
   \LARGE\sffamily\bfseries\mathversion{bold}#1\par}%
  \vskip2\baselineskip}
\makeatother
```

[image]

I'm not really sure of the intended use; the above was just cobbled together to match the request, but there may be more/better ideas to make something more robust (for example, if you have more than 9 chapters).

Comment: Sure, by the way that solution solved my problem within the first 9 chapters. Thanks!